# Dedupe and merge fields in a collection with Lodash (or vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've been looking at this way too long and the answer's probably obvious, but I'm trying to combine a few arrays of objects.
Given 2 arrays of objects, I need to dedupe them based on the name field, but combine the actions array:

```
var map1 = [{
    name: 'FOO',
    actions: [{bar: 'bar1'}]
}, {
    name: 'FOO2',
    actions: [{bar: 'bar2'}]
}]
var map2 = [{
    name: 'FOO',
    actions: [{bar: 'bar3'}]
}]
```

The desired output would be:

```
[
    {
        name: 'FOO',
        actions: [{bar: 'bar1'}, {bar: 'bar3'}] //merged by name "FOO"
    },
    {
        name: 'FOO2',
        actions: [{bar: 'bar2'}]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vanillaJS method. Note that your original objects had errors in their syntax which were corrected here.

You can use reduce to track the arrays by keys in order to be able to add to their action arrays using the `[...]` spread syntax. Because we want an array at the end, not an object, the whole result is passed through `Object.values`

```js
let map1 = [{
  name: 'FOO',
  actions: [{
    bar: 'bar1'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'FOO2',
  actions: [{
    bar: 'bar2'
  }]
}]
let map2 = [{
  name: 'FOO',
  actions: [{
    bar: 'bar3'
  }]
}]

let result = Object.values([...map1, ...map2].reduce((b, a) => {
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.name)) b[a.name].actions = [...b[a.name].actions, ...a.actions];
  else b[a.name] = a;
  return b;
}, {}))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome stuff, would be nice if you would be able to make `a.name` and `a.actions` generic, then you can really re-use this!